# Botão de Incluir

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, android-studio

Boa noite, estou fazendo um projeto de TCC, e queria saber qual função eu posso utilizar no botões `+` e `-`. A ideia é um app de pedidos, onde quando se clica em `+` será adicionado um item, e quando clicar em `-` será removido um item. Estou usando o andoid studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Qual função poder usar" é algo muito genérico. Caso você queira fazer alguma ação quando um dos botões for pressionados, você tem duas alternativas.

**A primeira alternativa** é criar na classe dessa activity (nesse caso, a sua "BurguerKing.java") um OnClickListener nos dois botões.

Pra isso, você vai precisar dar um findView nos dois componentes

```
private <Componente> botaoAdicionar = findViewById(R.id.<seuID>);
```

Depois, pra criar o OnClickListener

```
botaoAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Faça o que desejar
        }
    });
```

A **segunda alternativa** (não muito recomendada) é criar uma função e vincular ela ao seu componente. Pra isso, crie a função, clique no seu botão e vá em `inputMethod`. Lá, você seleciona a função que criou.

Caso queira adicionar e remover itens, vai precisar de um ArrayList. Caso os itens que você queira adicionar tenha características específicas, como por exemplo, `nome do pedido, preço, quantidade, etc...` você vai precisar criar um objeto com essas características e um Array desse objeto.

```
ArrayList<Pedido> listaDePedidos = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
```

Caso não esteja familiarizado com isso, recomendo dar uma lida em "Programação Orientada à Objetos".

Depois, claro, apenas usar os métodos do seu Array que adicionam e removem itens.

```
listaDePedidos.add(...);
listaDePedidos.remove(...);
```

Comment: Já me ajudou Bastante, eu estava precisando de um Norte para implementar as funções.